# SyntaxError: expected expression, got '&'

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I do a loop on my controller:

```
$events = '[';
while ($init->format('w') != $agenda->day){
    $events = $events . "{title: 'test', start: '" . $init->format('Y-m-d') . "'},";
    $init->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));            
}
$events = $events . ']';
```

the result is this string:

`[{title: 'test', start: '2018-09-15'},{title: 'test', start: '2018-09-16'},]`

On my blade page, I have a `script` to generate a fullcalendar and I put the code on it:

```
events:
    {{$eventos}},
```

But inside the `script` my code change to:

`[{title: &#039;test&#039;, start: &#039;2018-09-15&#039;},{title: &#039;test&#039;, start: &#039;2018-09-16&#039;},]`

and I receive the error:

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '&'

How to do the `script` read `'` rather than `&#039;`?

Comment: Don't try to build JSON yourself, php has a function for generating json: `json_encode`.

Comment: @PatrickEvans how do I convert my strings on json using `json_encode`? I am noob ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating the json string in your loop, define an array to pass to the view.

```
$events = []; 
while ($init->format('w') != $agenda->day){
    $events[] = [
        'title' => 'test', 
        'start' => $init->format('Y-m-d')
    ];
    $init->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));            
}
```

Then in the view file use the @json blade directive to output your array as json.

```
events: @json($events);
```